# How to determine the scroll direction(bottom or top) when using ViewChange event for ScrollViewer UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to find the scroll direction when subscribing to ViewChange event for a ScrollViewer in UWP.

So this event is being called on every scroll that I perform(up and down). I need to perform actions only when scrolling to bottom and ignore when scrolling up. Is this possible ?

```
private async void OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsIntermediate)
        {
          //here I need to know the scroll direction
        }
    }
```

Comment: scrollviewer has a verticaloffset and a horizontaloffset that gives the scroll offset at a given point in time.  Storing this between events and then getting the difference should, I think, give you a direction based on it being positive or negative.